# How can I input time(datatype) in java using netbeans gui

Tags: java, netbeans

I am just a beginner in java. I am developing an application using netbeans(i know very little about this also). Now there is an option for time in my application and it must insert 24 hour time(it must insert 23:45 etc and not a string/integer datatype) Is there any class for doing that. I need to do it using the GUI in netbeans(just drag and drop). 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JTextField and get text from it and tokenize it.

```
String time = jTextField1.getText();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(time, ":");
List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        timeList.add(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Spinner` component to add a time chooser. Since you are composing your grapical interface using NetBeans tools, you will need to add the below code block once done with your visual editing:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Your JFrame");
//Code inserted by netbeans...
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sdm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(dsm);
JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm");
spinner.setEditor(dateEditor);
frame.add(spinner,BorderLayout.NORTH); //Choose you position and where to add the component
```